# Getting /bin/sh Docker not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, amazon-ecr

I am trying to deploy a Windows container to AWS ECR using Gitlab CI:
Here is the Gitlab yaml file:

```
variables:
  AWS_REGISTRY: ****************.amazonaws.com/devops
  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: *****
  APP_NAME: devops

windows:
  stage: build
  tags:
  - prod
  before_script:
    ./docker_install.sh > /dev/null
  script:
  - docker build -t ${AWS_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH} 
  - docker push ${AWS_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}
```

Docker file is

```
FROM  mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
CMD [ "cmd" ]
```

Error is :

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.8.0 (*****)
  on *********-aws-gitlab-runner-prod ******
Resolving secrets
00:00
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:02
Using Docker executor with image alpine:latest ...
Pulling docker image alpine:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:*************** for alpine:latest with digest alpine@sha256:********************* ...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on runner-***************** via ******************.compute.internal...
Getting source from Git repository
00:02
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/jostens/devops/ci-images/docker-base-windows-2019-std-core/.git/
Checking out 76498ebe as main...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
/bin/sh: eval: line 110: docker: not found
$ docker build -t ${AWS_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}:${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG} .
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127
```

Please Help/advice